# pd.series changes the value of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a Calendar heatmaps from a csv that contains 
rainy values (VM) and dates (ISTANTE).

```
IDSTAZ,SENSORE,ISTANTE,VM
56,300001896,201601010000,0.0
56,300001896,201601020000,0.2
56,300001896,201601030000,0.6
56,300001896,201601040000,1.8
```

Searching on the web I have write the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import calmap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('D:\\GIS\\Dati\\Meteo_arpav\\stazione_forno.csv')
df['DateTime'] = df['ISTANTE'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d%H%M'))
events = pd.Series((df['VM']), index=df['DateTime'])
a=calmap.calendarplot(events)
plt.show(a)
```

It worked but when I create the `series`all the values of VM became `NaN`.
Printing (events) this is the result:

```
DateTime
2016-01-01   NaN
2016-01-02   NaN
2016-01-03   NaN
2016-01-04   NaN
2016-01-05   NaN
2016-01-06   NaN
2016-01-07   NaN
2016-01-08   NaN
2016-01-09   NaN
```

In this way calendar heatmap comes out empty. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for creating `Series`:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ISTANTE'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
events = df.set_index('DateTime')['VM']
print (events)
DateTime
2016-01-01    0.0
2016-01-02    0.2
2016-01-03    0.6
2016-01-04    1.8
Name: VM, dtype: float64
```

Reason why dont work:

```
events = pd.Series((df['VM']), index=df['DateTime'])
```

is data alignment. Index of column `VM` (`Series`) want to align by `DatetimeIndex`, but values not match, so result is `NaN`s.

Comment: Great. This is the right answer!! 
I thought that the index was created with `events = pd.Series((df['VM']), index=df['DateTime'])`. Thank you very much @jezrael